# Delineate watershed

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, hydrology, qswat

I have a problem with [QSWAT](https://swat.tamu.edu/software/qswat/). It does not take the delimitation of my catchment, I did all the solutions that I know.
I downloaded a new SRTM and the same projection with all the parameters. I digitized my hydrographic network from my topographic maps and I do it again but no result.

[image]